# IE 9 css trouble with positioning

Tags: css, internet-explorer

**Updated with code and screenshots to better follow SO's rules - hat-tip to Rocket**

Can anyone tell me, why this page

http://drivetimekl.mapicture.com/results/be50f539b0a7134cd2d0

Doesn't look the same in Chrome (correct display) and IE 9 (incorrect display) ?

Chrome screenshot: http://i59.tinypic.com/308l5dl.png

IE9 screenshot: http://i61.tinypic.com/33y24uc.png

On IE 9, the legend box is moved down and the logo is moved out of the screen.

I use leafletjs for the map, and apart from that I just try to position the divs with position: absolute and either top or bottom css property.

The HTML code in question:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="legend"></div>
<div id="legendTime">
  <ul class="legenTitle"></ul>
  <ul class="legendTime"></ul>
</div>
<div id="infoBoxDiv"></div>
<div id="maplogo">
  <a href="#"><img src="mapicture-logo.png" /></a>
</div>
```

And the css for legend and mapLogo:

```
#legend {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 13px;
  width: 285px;
  height: 210px;
  padding: 9px 0px 6px 20px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font: 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #777;
}

#maplogo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  left: 13px;
  width: 280px;
  height: 57px;
}
```

When I inspect through Chrome's debugger, I can see that leaflet's map-div gets the style "position: relative;". Does that somehow interfere with my "position: absolute"?

Comment: Please see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: In short, `#legendTime` is empty in IE9. Something broke.

Comment: Sorry Rocket - I will update my question with screenshots and code ASAP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should play with **z-index** property on #legend, #legendTime and #maplogo.

Add for example:

```
z-index:100;
```

to **#legend**, **#legendTime**, **#maplogo**